# The connection was not closed, The connection's current state is open

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm writing an ASP.NET application. In my datalayer an sql connection is being opened and closed before and after querying. The SqlConnection is being kept as a private field of a single class. Every database call in the class uses the same structure:

```
        conn.Open();

        try
        {
            // database querying here
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Yet, on very rare occasions I get the exception 'The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open'. It's not possible to reproduce the problem since it originates very rarely from different parts of the code. There is some threading involved in my application but new threads also make new data layer classes and thus new connection objects.

I do not understand how it's possible to have a connection lingering around open using the code above. Shouldn't the connection always be closed after opening, making it impossible for the above exception to occur?

Comment: The important thing here is where your conn object is being instancianted?

Comment: Also: what's wrong with using 'using'?

Comment: Just use a using statement instead? Guarantee's the connection to be closed and disposed.

Comment: If it is possible, try wrapping your connection in a `using(SQLConnection conn = new SQLConnection(xxx)) { ... }` statement and see if you can still reproduce the error. This way, the SQLconnection gets cleaned up by the GC, when the code is exited

Comment: **Where** do you get that exception? In the code posted? If not, can you post more of the code?

Comment: did you used datareader ?

Comment: If you used datareader , Then must close the datareader object . because the datareader is connected architecture  .

Comment: The SqlConnection is instantiated in the constructor of my dataaccess class, so it's use class-wide.

I use SqlDataAdapter in the try-block.

I guess making a new connection object with using would solve the problem. However I'd still like to understand the problem. I don't see how it's possible the connection is ever open when conn.Open() is being called.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's likely that an exception is being thrown in the `try` block that you aren't handling. See this note in MSDN for [try-finally](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwc8s4fz.aspx):

> Within a handled exception, the associated finally block is guaranteed to be run. However, if the exception is unhandled, execution of the finally block is dependent on how the exception unwind operation is triggered.

I would recommend wrapping the connection in a `using` block anyway:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
     //etc...
}
```

Alternatively, add a catch block to the `try-finally`:

```
    conn.Open();

    try
    {

    }
    catch
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, this explain why conn.Close() is sometimes not ran. I was somehow in the belief that finally { } would always run no matter what.

Comment: No problem. If this answers your question you should consider marking it as the answer to help other users facing similar problems.

Comment: @user2830395 You were right, the finally block does execute no matter what, even if an exception occurs. If the code in this answer solved the issue, it was because of another factor.

Answer (score 4):

you should close connections as soon as you operations finished. Try to open connections for the shortest time possible.
However it is best to use **using** it will call Dispose method even in case of exceptions.

```
using (SqlConnection conn= new SqlConnection(conStr))
{
     //etc...
}
```

**OR**

**1)** Open the connection

**2)** Access the database

**3)** Close the connection

```
 //conn.Open();

        try
        {
          conn.Open();
          //Your Code

        }
        finally
        {
           conn.Close();   
           conn.Dispose();//Do not call this if you want to reuse the connection
        }
```

Comment: That does not close the connection if there was an issue inside the try...
The close SHOULD be in the finally, which means that the conn needs to be declared outside of the try.

Answer (score -1):

```
using (SqlConnection conn= new SqlConnection(conStr))
{

 // ETC

}
```

is the best solution since you maybe want to reuse the connection again. Just using & dipose won't help you, so checking on it before open is better.