# How to get rid of "The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open." error?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

i have this code that everytime i run, this error comes out;

```
 "The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open."
```

Eventhough i had already closed the connection. here is the code below

```
Private Sub cmbInstructorID_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmbInstructorID.SelectedIndexChanged
    Try
        sqlCon.Open()
        Dim QUERY As String
        QUERY = "SELECT IntructorID, [Last Name] + ', ' + [First Name] + ' ' + LEFT([First Name],1)+'.' FROM UtlyInstructor WHERE IntructorID = '" & cmbInstructorID.Text & "'"
        CMD = New SqlCommand(QUERY, sqlCon)
        Reader = CMD.ExecuteReader
        While Reader.Read
            cmbInstructorName.Text = Reader.GetString(1)
        End While
        sqlCon.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

How do i get rid of it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089305/the-connection-was-not-closed-the-connections-current-state-is-open

Comment: Also, look up how to parametrize your query. It's a very bad idea to concatenate like that.

Comment: Then how do i do it? can you give me an idea, a sample code maybe.?

Comment: At this line `sqlCon.Open()` your connection is already open. You can't reopen it.

Comment: Well taken. Thank guys..